# How to change text to bold dynamically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have text box in which I can type text using windows phone keyboard. My requirement is, while I am typing and when I click on a button with name say Bold, after this click the text which I will type next should be in Bold and when I click on the button again, it should stop that function and the next typed text should be in normal text. For Example: Hello, **I am good**. How are you?

I am trying passing the text box text to a web browser and then storing the string into variable. But not getting the exact solution for my requirement. Please help me out with this. Any example or link with code will be more helpful in understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To do this 'properly' you are going to have ot wait for the [Mango RichTextBox](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control) to become available. Before that, I think your approach using a `WebControl` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the concept of a RichTextBox control on Windows Phone. Out of the box, there is no such control in the SDK. There is a static [RichTextBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/06/01/where-is-richtextbox-in-the-mango-beta.aspx) that can be used to display rich text contents (more details [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control)), but not a dynamic one (that accepts user input).

There are [third-party controls](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/C1PhoneRichTextBox/default.htm?turl=componentonerichtextboxforwindowsphoneoverview.htm), though, that accomplish the task you are looking for.